# jQuery $.get to http from https site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl, cross-domain

On my webpage I've integrated a foscam webcam. It worked like a charm, until I switched my domain from http to https. The problem seems to be that you're not allowed to communicate with a non-https site (foscam can only communicate over http) from the https site. That seems to make perfectly sense if you think about it from a security perspective, but I would like to know if there's a way around it

To integrate the webcam, I use this script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function reload()
{
   setTimeout('reloadImg("refresh")',10)
};

function reloadImg(id) 
{ 
   var obj = document.getElementById(id); 
   var date = new Date(); 
   obj.src = "http://www.somedomain.com/snapshot.cgi?user=username&pwd=mypw&t=" + Math.floor(date.getTime()/10); 
} 

@endif
</script>
```

and

```
<img src="http://www.somedomain.com/snapshot.cgi?user=username&pwd=mypw&t" name="refresh" id="refresh" onload='reload(this)' onerror='reload(this)'>
```

That still works (although the console does show errors like

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.somedomain.nl/webcam' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.somedomain.nl/snapshot.cgi?user=user&pwd=pass!&t=145244729934'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

The real problem that I have is with the buttons to control the webcam. 
For that I use code like:

```
 $("#left").click(function(){
             $.get( "http://www.somedomain.nl/decoder_control.cgi?command=6&user=username&pwd=pass&onestep=1",
 function( data ) {});
         });
```

These buttons do not work anymore, and generate the following error in the console:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.somedomain.nl/webcam' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.somedomain.nl/decoder_control.cgi?command=2&user=someuser&pwd=pass!&onestep=1'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.send @ jquery.js:8625jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8161jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8306(anonymous function) @ webcam:38jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4430elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4116

Is there any way around this?

Comment: There is a related question here (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56779/securing-remotely-accessible-ip-cameras-that-do-not-support-https), explaining how to expose the camera through https. It's involved, but if you are connecting over the actual internet it might be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Making the camera communicate over https using a reverse proxy was indeed the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should change http to https:

```
 $("#left").click(function(){
             $.get( "https://www.somedomain.nl/decoder_control.cgi?command=6&user=username&pwd=pass&onestep=1",
 function( data ) {});
         });
```

**EDIT**: [link](http://foscam.us/forum/how-to-use-rtsp-and-https-for-hd-cameras-t4926.html):

> The method how to use https visit:
>   Type https://cameraip:https port/ in the browser directly to login the camera.

But this feature requires new firmware:

> The new firmware support HTTPS, it improved the security when you login your camera.

Comment: thanks, but the camera is a FI8910W, which does not support https. I was able to let it communicate over https using a reverse proxy, like mentioned in this tutorial: https://bitsofinfo.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/securing-foscam-ip-camera-access-over-ssl-with-apache-reverse-proxying/